# Find all integers $n$ such that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Question: Find all integers $n$ such that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group.

Thoughts: I know that $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $n$ and $u$ are coprime.  So, in each ring, there are $\phi(n)$ units.  But I am not sure if there is a "nice" way to see if every non-trivial element in $U(n)$ has order $2$.  I was thinking of breaking it down into even and odd $n$, or considering how many units each ring has, but I wasn't able to notice anything useful.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

The question is asked here: [For what values of $n$ is $U(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ an elementary abelian 2-group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3259033/for-what-values-of-n-is-u-mathbbz-n-an-elementary-abelian-2-group), but I wasn't able to get to a conclusion on based on the last hint.

Comment: If $n \neq 3$ is odd, then $2^2=4 \not \equiv 1 \pmod n$, so you only have to worry about even $n$.

Comment: You can use the  Chinese Remainder Theorem to reduce it to the prime power case, and in that situation it is easy.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Based on Robert's comment, I would only have to worry about even $n$, and based on yours, I would only have to worry about when $n=2$?  I'm not sure how I would use the CRT in this case, though.

Comment: @User7238: No, he is approaching it without decomposition, I am suggesting a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since the units of $A\times B$ are $U(A)\times U(B)$, and a product is elementary $2$-abelian if and only if both factors are elementary $2$-abelian, we can reduce first to the prime power case. The answer then will be any $n$ that can be written as a product of "suitable" prime powers.

If $p$ is an odd prime, then $(\mathbb{Z}/p^a\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic of order $p^{a-1}(p-1)$. For this to be elementary $2$-abelian, we need this number to be $2$ (the only cyclic elementary $2$-abelian group). So $a=1$ and $p=3$.

For powers of $2$, the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}/2^a\mathbb{Z}$ is: trivial if $a=1$; cyclic of order $2$ if $a=2$; and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/2^{a-2}\mathbb{Z}$ if $a\geq 3$. So this is elementary $2$-abelian if and only if $a\leq 3$.

Thus, $n$ must be of the form $n=2^a3^b$ with $0\leq a\leq 3$ and $0\leq b\leq 1$.

Answer (score 4):

By Robert Shore's comment, for odd $n$, we have only $n=3$ working.

For even $n$, write $n=2^k m$ with odd $m$. By CRT as suggested by Arturo Magidin,
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^* \times (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})^*. 
$$
Again if $m>3$, there is an element of order greater than $2$. Thus, we have $m=1, 3$.

If $k\geq 2$, then we have
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/2^k\mathbb{Z})^* \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/2^{k-2}\mathbb{Z}).
$$
So, the group has an element of order greater than $2$ if $k>3$.

Hence, we must have
$n=1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24$.

Here, $n=1,2$ yield trivial groups. $n=3,4,6$ yield $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and $n=8,12$ yield $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$, $n=24$ yield $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$.